# The new site has too many ads

Tags: discussion

I'm all for a few ads around the edges, but putting them front and center, even inside questions on some sites, is distracting. It pollutes the academic flavor of stackexchange.

Here is an example. This same ad appears twice more as I scroll down, practically heading the answers.

[image]

This is the sort of thing that could lose users over the long term.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get reduced ads by hitting 200 reputation on any site that has ads. This pares them down to a good degree.

Additionally, the Network is very much OK with you using a browser addon to block the ads entirely.

That said, I don't think that the taller top bar has any relation to the ads. Cross Validated doesn't have the new layout yet, only Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange do.

Comment: can confirm that that's how sites with the old, non responsive UI with ads look like

Comment: Yes, this is the old UI. Stats.stackexchange hasn't been updated yet. But there are definitely more ads than there were last week. Someone saw fit to prioritize the revenue stream. Good to know 200 reputation reduces them.

Comment: @pvlkmrv Those ads have always existed - they'e not in any way new. You probably just rarely saw them because there weren't any to show you most of the time.